# Is "Thanks a ton" a commonly used phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Is it correct to say so? Does this mean the same as "thanks a lot"?

Comment: New to me, but but _thanks a million_ might be heard sometimes.

Comment: Not too many references in search results [see here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1272440)
Seems to be not very spread.

Comment: To answer your other question, yes, I'd interpret it to mean the same as "thanks a lot," "thanks a bunch," "thanks a million," or "thanks much" (or, for that matter, just, "Thanks!"). Also, less _common_ doesn't necessarily imply less _correct_.  It all depends on if you want to say something commonly said, or say something that has a bit more novelty to it.

Comment: Don't know about "commonly used", but I am one person who uses it occasionally, and I certainly haven't invented it.

Comment: There are many variations, all of the form "thanks (large quantity)". A particular vexing example for a non-native speaker is "thanks loads".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's *commonly* used, but it's certainly not unheard of.  [This NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thanks+a+ton%2Cthanks+a+bunch&year_start=1990&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that it's not nearly as common as 'thanks a bunch' but it does at least register on the scale.  Both pale in comparison to the far more prevalent ['thanks a lot'](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thanks%20a%20ton,thanks%20a%20bunch,thanks%20a%20lot,%20thanks%20much&year_start=1990&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Answer (score 2):

The commonly used expression, in AmE, is *thanks a million*. I think *thanks a ton* has derived from the same expression and eventually found its way to the mainstream. I can't find anything for *thanks a ton* in NOAD, but see an entry for *thanks a million*. Furthermore, I can't find the same expression registered in OED, which makes it chiefly American.

Comment: Makes sense. The rest of the world is metric. :-)

Comment: @Urbycoz Exactly! I wrote an answer that incorporated that observation. Actually, it is a fact. I feel guilty, as I got the idea from you. I can acknowledge you by name in my answer if you want. Since you didn't answer yourself, I didn't have a URL to include.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly an "American" variant. It's just a *very* "non-standard" variant on *thanks a **million/lot/bundle/bunch/etc**.* Those last two are particularly likely to be [facetious/ironical](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PA645&dq=%22thanks+a+bundle+used%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PS-hULqkEpKV0QWsuoHoCQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22thanks%20a%20bundle%20used%22&f=false), but *million* is usually sincere, and *lot* can be used either way.

Answer (score 2):

In American English, *thanks a ton* is atypical in written form. I have heard it spoken, not too often though. As others said, *thanks a lot*, or *thanks a million*, or *thanks a bunch* or even *thanks much* would be spoken and understood more often. Any of those would be informal but not slang usage in written American English.

**Ton** is not a metric unit, but rather, an English (Imperial?) system unit of the sort we use here in the U.S.A. as mentioned by @Urbycoz in a comment. Despite that, *thanks a ton* is less common than other expressions, even in American English. You will probably be understood though.

Given that the intent is to express gratitude, it is especially important to be easily understood! I would use an expression where there isn't any chance of misinterpretation.

Comment: +1 for the interesting observations.  It got me thinking about our (US) usage of ton to mean "many" as in "Thanks a ton", "heavy" as in "like a ton of bricks", "much" as in "I have tons of homework".

Comment: The ton may be an Imperial unit, but the tonne is a metric unit, and in speech they're indistinguishable.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That is a valid point, regarding pronunciation. I'll revert then to making the case for written form, and mention that "Thanks a tonne" is even more peculiar than "Thanks a ton". Am I responding to your comment logically, or at cross-purposes? I'm confused now, sorry!

Comment: If I had a point (which I maybe didn't), it was that without a bit more research there's no obvious reason for expecting it to be more common in en-us than other dialects. (Although I can't find any instance with either spelling in BNC, so if there's one in COCA that would be interesting).